# mvc 4 localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I'm trying to use localization in my project. I created MVC 4 project and added resourses.resx file. But when i try to access this file from _Layout.schtml studio say that name 'Resources' doesn't exist in current context.

[image]

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Resources.ResourceName.Property` when you want to access your resource from cshtml

Don't forget to make your resource Public access

Comment: Try to look here http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-globalizationlocalization.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the namespace of your resources in an `@using` statement in the beginning of the page (the `_Layout.cshtml` file), or either add the namespace to the beginning.

In your case, add `@using kazwaySite` and it should work. Also, be aware that the access modifier of your Resource, is set to `public`. Open your resource file, and you'll see this this (see below) on the top your screen:

[image: Change access modifier resource]